# Cocoa-Touch: How to allow MPMoviePlayerController but no other views to autorotate?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have this iOS 3.2 app (iPad) which has lots of content, and a few videos.

All the views are in portrait, except for the videos which are portrait inline, with a fullscreen option, and I'd like to let the user autorotate the video while fullscreen.

In `shouldAutorotateForInterfaceOrientation:` my app generally refuses autorotation.

How can I let MPMoviePlayerController's view autorotate, but not any other views in my app?

A few ideas I've thought of:

1. in `shouldAutorotateForInterfaceOrientation:`:
   `return isFullscreenMovieActive;`
   which would make the app allow rotation while a movie is in fullscreen mode. This works perfectly except for one huge issue, I cannot force the app back into portrait mode once the user exits fullscreen mode. (i.e. user starts app, finds a movie player, plays it, goes to fullscreen mode, rotates the device, presses done, now he has the app in landscape mode)
   Is there an acceptable way to force rotating to a `UIInterfaceOrientation`?
2. Apple actually recommends grabbing `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view from it's view method. When the device rotates, what actually happens is that the app's `UIWindow` gets a `CGAffineTransform` applied to it. So I could do this to `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view, but when entering fullscreen mode the view changes and is not the one in the view property.
   So is there any acceptable way to get `MPMoviePlayerController`'s fullscreen view?

Or is there a better solution for this task?

Comment: Support landscape mode in your app?

Comment: @tc: that's just it, I'd like to support it, but I can't find a way to force the iPad back to portrait orientation after the user exits the fulscreen video. I have a very special case where the orientation MUST be portrait for a good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each view controller can return the orientations it supports with `shouldAutorotateForInterfaceOrientation:`. Your app's controllers should only return true for the portrait rotations, except for the `MPMoviePlayerController`. When your app displays the video, present the `MPMoviePlayerController` over your other view controller with `presentModalViewController:animated:` (or `presentViewController:animated:completion:` in iOS 5). Once the video is done, dismiss the special movie player controller, and your other controller should still be in portrait mode.